# Correct way to use shared style modules in Polymer 3

Tags: css, polymer, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, polymer-3.x

In my project I would like to use shared styles but have no idea how can I write it correctly for IE11 and Edge.

I'm using polymer 3 with JS imports and this solutions works for Google Chrome, but in IE11/Edge doesn't work or works partially.

Now I have `common-styles.js`

```
const styleElementCommon = document.createElement('dom-module');

styleElementCommon.innerHTML = `
    <template>
        <style>
            :host > * {
                --black: #000;
                --white: #fff;
                --blue: #2862a1;
            }
            :host * {  
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
        </style>
    </template>
`;
styleElementCommon.register('common-styles');
```

Then I have a `layout-styles.js` which is inherits from `common-styles.js`

```
import './common-styles';

const styleElementLayout = document.createElement('dom-module');

styleElementLayout.innerHTML = `
    <template>
        <style include="common-styles">
            :host > * {
                --headerHeight: 120px;
                --footerHeight: 60px;

                --sidebarWidth: 100vw;
                --sideMenuWidth: 100vw;
        </style>
    </template>
`;
styleElementLayout.register('layout-styles');
```

And then, I have a `header-layout.js` which has own styles plus shared styles.

```
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import '../../styles/layout-styles';

const template = html`
    <style include="layout-styles">
        header {
            height: var(--headerHeight);
        }
        header.background-blue {
            background: var(--blue);
        }
    </style>
    <header class="background-blue">
        <slot></slot>
    </header>
`;

class HeaderLayout extends PolymerElement {
    static get is() {
        return 'header-layout';
    }

    static get properties() {
        return {}
    }

    static get template() {
        return template;
    }
}

window.customElements.define('header-layout', HeaderLayout);
```

My logic is following.
`header-layout.js` include `layout-styles.js` and `layout-styles.js` include `common-styles.js`.

The result is that `header-layout.js` has accessible all variables from layout and common styles.

This is works everywhere except Edge and IE11.
In Edge are accessible only variables from layout styles and IE11 doesn't work all.

When I remove `include` attribute from common and layout styles. IE11 works like Edge before - has only variables from layout styles

What is the correct way how share more styles for component across browsers?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Polymer document](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/about_30), Polymer 3.0 has moved from HTML Imports to ES6 Modules, and from Bower to npm. Some features used by Polymer are not (yet) supported natively in all browsers, we need to use the [Polyfills](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/polyfills).

Besides, you could check your Browser version and the [Polymer Browser Support document](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/browsers). I have tested [this sample](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/PNsZA1) on my side. it works well on Microsoft Edge 44 version, but not working in IE browser. Since this issue is related to the Polymer, I suggest you could post your issue on [Polymer forum](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed++shared+style+modules).